# Parsing amazon (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

hello i'm trying to parse amazon but my code didn't working

```
soup=bs(driver.page_source,'html.parser')

driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/gp/newreleases/wireless/18007875011/ref=zg_bs_tab_t_bsnr')

for card in soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'aok-inline-block zg-item'}):
    elem = card.find('a', {'class': 'a-size-small a-link-normal'})
    if elem:
        print(elem.text)
    else:
        print("no")


<a class="a-size-small a-link-normal" href="/product-reviews/B08LKSB44H/ref=zg_bsnr_18007875011_cr_1?ie=UTF8&amp;refRID=ANMANQSPHMGGBN5V69MT">38</a>
```

My code prints nothing
i want to parse whole page review example '38'

[image: i want to parse whole page]

Comment: The amazon link in your question doesn't work for me. It's either not available for me (due to country restrictions maybe) or the URL is not correct.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/kitchen/ref=pd_zg_ts_kitchen this link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply get the page source after `driver.get`.

```
driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/kitchen/ref=pd_zg_ts_kitchen')
soup=bs(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
for card in soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'aok-inline-block zg-item'}):
    elem = card.find('a', {'class': 'a-size-small a-link-normal'})
    if elem:
        print(elem.text)
    else:
        print("no")
```

Outputs

```
103,695
5,192
553
8,550
63,871
150,219
33,163
20,676
60,099
74,622
56,936
38,668
26,801
23,081
37,602
26,418
36,130
13,676
32,809
59,833
11,368
27,405
35,041
no
1,625
53,291
34,065
30,571
3,368
3,314
11,069
37,988
14,216
10,260
28,815
3,689
6,305
13,366
11,563
30
19,071
969
27,697
21,310
26,946
332
7,920
25,876
18,449
6,471
```